# Запуск Spring Boot приложения

Tags: spring-boot

Подскажите пожалуйста как настроить запуск Spring Boot приложения по адресу [http://localhost:8099/имяМоегоПриложения](http://localhost:8099/%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), а не по адресу http://localhost:8099

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть 2 способа.

1. Рекомендуемый. В конфигурационном файле приложения (application.properties/.yml), прописать `server.servlet.contextPath=/имяМоегоПриложения`
2. При запуске приложения добавить системную переменную:

```
public static void main(String[] args { 
    System.setProperty("server.servlet.context-path","/имяМоегоПриложения");
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

Источник: [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-path)